Understanding of the set of all Kähler forms on a compact complex manifold $X$ is an open convex cone in $\{\omega\in\mathcal A^{1,1}(X)|d\omega=0\}$
I am reading Complex Geometry by Daniel Huybrechts. I have a problem when reading the proof of the following corollary:

Proposition. The set of closed positive definite (i.e. $\omega$ is locally of the form $\omega=\frac{i}{2} \sum h_{i j} d z_{i} \wedge d \bar{z}_{j}$ such that $\left(h_{i j}\right)$ is positive definite at every point) real $(1,1)$-forms $\omega \in \mathcal{A}^{1,1}(X)$ is the set of all Kähler forms.
Corollary. The set of all Kähler forms on a compact complex manifold $X$ is an open convex cone in the linear space $\left\{\omega \in \mathcal{A}^{1,1}(X) \mid d \omega=0\right\}$.
Proof. The positivity of an hermitian matrix $\left(h_{i j}(x)\right)$ is an open property and, since $X$ is compact, the set of forms $\omega \in \mathcal{A}^{1,1}(X)$ that are locally of the form $\omega=\frac{i}{2} \sum h_{i j} d z_{i} \wedge d \bar{z}_{j}$ with $\left(h_{i j}\right)$ positive definite at every point is open. The differential equation $d \omega=0$ ensures that the metric associated to such an $\omega$ is Kähler.
In order to see that Kähler forms form a convex cone, one has to show that for $\lambda>0$ and Kähler forms $\omega_{1}$, $\omega_{2}$ also $\lambda \cdot \omega_{i}$ and $\omega_{1}+\omega_{2}$ are Kähler forms. Both assertion follow from the corresponding statements for positive definite hermitian matrices.

It's obvious that it is a convex cone, but I'm not sure why it is open.
First, the meaning of "open" that I understand is that this cone does not contain its boundary.
Then I don't know why "since $X$ is compact, the set of forms $\omega \in \mathcal{A}^{1,1}(X) \cap \mathcal{A}^{2}(X)$ that are locally of the form $\omega=\frac{i}{2} \sum h_{i j} d z_{i} \wedge d \bar{z}_{j}$ with $\left(h_{i j}\right)$ positive definite at every point is open". The author here simply states the definition of positive definite without providing any further explanation about the relationship between "$X$ is compact" and "the property is open". This makes me confused. I can roughly understand that positivity of matrix is an open property since its eigenvalues are strictly greater than $0$. Here "strictly" ensures "open".
EDITED:
Let $\eta$ be a closed $(1,1)$-form. Write $\eta=a_{ij}dz^i\wedge d\bar z^j$, then its norm is
$$|\eta|^2=\langle a_{ij}dz^i\wedge d\bar z^j,a_{kl}dz^k\wedge d\bar z^l\rangle=a_{ij}\bar a_{kl}\delta^{ik}\delta^{jl}=\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|^2.$$
According to Andrew D. Hwang's comment, it suffices to show that for every Kähler form $\omega_0$, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for every closed $(1,1)$-form $\eta$ of norm less than $\epsilon$, the form $\omega:=\omega_0+\eta$ is positive definite.
In other words, it suffices to show that for any $n\times n$ positive definite matrix $H_0(p)$ on $X$, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $n\times n$ matrix $A(p)=(a_{ij}(p))$ that satisfies $\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|^2<\epsilon$, the matrix $H(p):=H_0(p)+A(p)$ is positive definite, where $p\in X$. However, since $A(p)$ may not be conjugate symmetric, its eigenvalues may be complex.
Any help would be appreciated!

(1/2) IIRC, note that open is stronger than does not contain its boundary. Loosely, the Kähler cone contains none of its boundary points. <> The task is to show: For every Kähler form $\omega{0}$, there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for every exact $(1, 1)$-form $\eta$ of norm less than $\varepsilon$, the form $\omega := \omega_{0} + \eta$ is positive definite._ <> The choice of norm is crucial here. I haven't read Huybrechts, but as long as eigenvalues of a form are continuous, the following argument goes through:

(2/2) As you note, positivity of matrix is an open property since its eigenvalues are strictly greater than $0$. The key point is, the eigenvalues of a closed $(1, 1)$-form $\omega$ relative to the fixed form $\omega_{0}$ are continuous in $\eta$ with respect to the norm on the space of forms. Since $X$ is compact and the eigenvalue functions are positive, they are bounded away from $0$. <> Please post your own answer when you've worked out the details!

@AndrewD.Hwang D. I have edited my question and added my progress. Now I need show that for any $n\times n$ positive definite matrix $H_0(p)$ on $X$, there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $n\times n$ matrix $A(p)=(a_{ij}(p))$ that satisfies $\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|^2<\epsilon$, the matrix $H(p):=H_0(p)+A(p)$ is positive definite, where $p\in X$. However, since $A(p)$ may not necessarily be conjugate symmetric, its eigenvalues may be complex.

Commenting about the edit: the matrix $A$ is also Hermitian, so the eigenvalues will be real: $A$ is the matrix associated to a real $2$-form $\eta$ that is of type $(1,1)$.
